# png covering buttons using safari and chrome

Tags: css, png

I've created a home page with a featured image, which works fine with firefox, but the image overlaps the buttons, slightly, using safari and chrome.

I've tried everything to get the image to fall below the buttons, using z-index: and even added the image to a div as a background, but it still seems to want to sit on the top of everything when viewed with Chrome and Safari. I've not tried Edge or IE yet, I know it only seems to work with Firefox

http://aspirationalfutures.co.uk

Any help would be great

Comment: Looks fine on chrome

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] - and read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: in chrome of safari, if you run your mouse over the right hand side of the buttons on the left and the left of the buttons on the right, it picks the main featured image

Comment: and i've just noticed that the fade doesn't work, at al,l on both either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to correct the stacking order:

```
#one, #two {
  position: relative;
}
```

Add this to get the `opacity` working:

```
a.fade {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: perfect!! Thanks ovokuro!